# SQL Query by created 3 hours ago

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given a set of data with `date_created` stored like `2017-04-13 23:29:52`, how would I construct an SQL query to select all items that were created within the last 3 hours?

I originally thought to do something like this:

```
SELECT
  *,
  MAX(date_created)
FROM items
GROUP BY date_created
```

but that would not be exactly what I want. I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: exactly 3 hours ago? more than 3 hours ago?

Comment: Have you tried a `WHERE` clause in your query? Look into the `DATEDIFF` function.

Comment: You can simply use your_columnname - interval 3 hour

Comment: @WheatBeak between 3 hours and 3.5 hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NOW()` and `INTERVAL` in your `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE date_created <= NOW() - INTERVAL 180 minute AND date_created >= NOW() - INTERVAL 210 minute
```

Comment: Definitely the right idea, although I might suggest `INTERVAL 3 hour` as being easier to follow.

Comment: Yeah just personal preference I'd rather have whole number minutes than a float for hours.  No particular reason why, just me haha.

Comment: Although in testing for some reason `3.5 hour` doesn't seem to be as precise as `210 minute`.  For example, right now my server time is `15:01`, but if I use `3.5 hour` it will still return an entry with the time `11:28`.  I definitely recommend using minutes if precision is wanted.  Maybe that's why I started doing it that way in the first place.

Comment: In further testing I'm actually getting real strange behavior in using a float, not getting any errors but I'd definitely say stick to whole numbers.  Maybe someone who's much more versed in SQL can chime in and explain this.

Comment: Float is an approximation, and dates are literal number values. They don't mix well. Don't use floats in comparisons.

Comment: @WheatBeak . . . There is no need for floating point numbers.  Given that `interval` doesn't support them, they are even more pointless.

Answer (score 1):

This one uses CURDATE, CURDATE and DATE_ADD:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE DATE(date_created) = CURDATE()
AND TIME(date_created) BETWEEN CURTIME() AND DATE_ADD(CURTIME(), INTERVAL -3 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from items where 
extract(hours from age(current_timestamp, date_created))>=3;
```

Extract keyword would extract hours difference from current timestamp and return only that is greater than or equal to 3.